# error when I try to convert R code to python code

Tags: python, r

I want to convert R code below to python code. but when I run it using spider, I get this error?

> R2PyConversionError: Unable to convert

how can I solve it?

```
rscript = """
data("multishapes")

df <- multishapes[, 1:2]

n = 1
for(eps in seq(0.05, 0.15, 0.05)){
  for(minpPts in seq(2, 5, 1)){
    db <- fpc::dbscan(df, eps = eps, MinPts = minpPts)
    g = fviz_cluster(db, df, stand = FALSE, ellipse = FALSE, geom = "point") + 
      ggtitle(paste0('eps = ', eps, ' minPts = ', minpPts)) +  theme(legend.position="none") +
      theme(axis.title = element_text(size=14), plot.title = element_text(size = 16,colour="darkblue", 
                                                                    hjust = 0.5))
    ggsave(paste0('g',n,'.png'))
    n = n+1
  }}
system("convert -delay 200  -loop 0  *.png dbscan.gif")
file.remove(list.files(pattern=".png"))
"""
from pyensae.languages import rconverter
print(rconverter.r2python(rscript, pep8=True))
```

Comment: Try to identify where the problem is. Can you convert the first 2 lines? Can you convert the first 2 lines and the for loop? If not, can you convert some of the lines in the for loop? Maybe the problem is just one line. Though that R code seems to use quite a few packages: `fpc`, `factoextra`, `ggplot2`... I'd be very very surprised if it is simply "convertible" to Python. You'd probably be better off using `rpy2` to actually call R from Python.

Comment: here it the entire error message I'm getting. I didn't allow me to add it above. I'm not sure exactly what is the problem since I tried to install some packages before I tried to convert the R code.

Comment: R2PyConversionError: Unable to convert
'::'
<class 'antlr4.tree.Tree.TerminalNodeImpl'>
::
PARENT
'[352 271 350 269 355 131 530 148 355 131 530 148 96]'
<class 'pyensae.languages.RParser.RParser.RangeopContext'>
---SOFAR---
data ( "multishapes" ) 
df = multishapes [ range( 1 , 2 ) ] 
n = 1 
for eps in seq ( 0.05 , 0.15 , 0.05 ) :    
    for minpPts in seq ( 2 , 5 , 1 ) :

Comment: ---SOSTACK---
('Identifier', <antlr4.tree.Tree.TerminalNodeImpl object at 0x0000028DE5FF56C0>)
('Affectop', <antlr4.tree.Tree.TerminalNodeImpl object at 0x0000028DE5FDEAC0>)
('Identifier', <antlr4.tree.Tree.TerminalNodeImpl object at 0x0000028DE5FF5700>)
---END---
MESSAGE=
Rangeop

Comment: Replace fpc::dbscan by dbscan alone. Add a line library(fpc) atop the r code inside string.

Comment: "`Unable to convert '::'`" seems pretty clear. The converter can't handle the `::` syntax, which is used in R to call a function from a package. Since this R code uses several packages, I don't think you will be able to convert it to python code. I'll echo what I said above: you'd probably be better off using rpy2 to actually call R from Python

Comment: Of course that function is a dumb translator that only do a very basic verbatim transcription, your code will not work.

Comment: I removed '::', and I code a code. but when I tried to run the generated python code, I got many error messages saying undefined names